# Mouse cursor not changing possition after being moved

Tags: java, swing, awt, coordinates, mouse

So, I am trying to make a program, and for it to start, i need the user to click on a start button, which is a square on the upper left-hand side of the screen, my way of seeing if the cursor is in the button is: checking the mouse's coordinates, seeing if those coordinates are inside the button, and reacting accordingly (starting the program or not), but, when I start the program, it just takes the mouse's coordinates and doesn't change them when i move them, so, for example, if the mouse starts on x:0 y:0, and i move it to x:100 y:100 and then click, the program thinks it's on 0,0 and doesn't do anything even though the cursor is in the button, and, as far as I can see, there's not much I can do (that's why I am asking here) The code that makes this happen is this: (the button doesn't start anything yet, it just changes the text on screen)

```
 public class MouseHandler implements MouseListener
{

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(mX < 200 && mY < 200 && mX > 100 && mY > 100)
        {
            textLabel.setText("button pressed");
        } else {
            textLabel.setText("You're not pressing the button" );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to check the click coordinates when you can just use a higher-level button press handler?  How this is coded depends on what framework you are using, but it's already built-in.

Comment: @Jim Garrison I don't know what a button press handler is, as i am relatively new to java, and checking coordinates was the way the yt tutorial i watched used, would you mind explaining what it is to me? Thanks

Comment: Your framework will provide higher-level event methods for a lot of user actions.  You haven't told us what framework you are using (AWT, SWT, Swing, something else).  Your next action should be to study the tutorial(s) available for your framework and read the Javadoc.  UI programming is not something you can just pick up piecemeal, it requires a significant amount of study to understand.

Comment: Better to use an `ActionListener` with a `JButton`. It will react to both mouse **and keyboard** input. Note also that a mouse listener will give co-ordinates relative to the component to which it is added. If you cannot get it fixed from that tip, post a [mre].